# Export database from MySQL v5.5 to MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb, mysql-5.7, mysql-5.5

My old database is deployed using MySQL v5.5, however when I export/dump to data using:

```sh
mysqldump -u root -p database_name > database_name.sql
```

Then import that data into my new database using MySQL v5.7, using:

```sql
source database_name.sql;
```

There are then tables missing. There are hundreds of tables so I can't check the reason for all of them. However, for one of them the reason is:

`ROW_FORMAT=FIXED` is no longer an option for the InnoDB Storage Engine in [v5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_default_row_format)

With the relevant SQL statment from `database_name.sql` being:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `catalog_product_website` (
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Product ID',
  `website_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Website ID',
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`website_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID` (`website_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=FIXED COMMENT='Catalog Product To Website Linkage Table';
```

1. My main question is, is there a way to export/dump the data so that I can know it'll be full compatible with MySQL v5.7?
2. Is this the only compatibilty issue that could exist, if so is it safe to just grep these statments?

Comment: Can you edit the dump and do a simple find/replace of `ROW_FORMAT=FIXED` to nothing? Someone else [had similar trouble](https://github.com/sequelpro/sequelpro/issues/2478) going from 5.0 to 5.7 with the same.

Comment: That's definetly an option, I just don't know what the effect of this will be and whether this would cause data to be misssing. As I can't feasibly check.